# Change of basis wrt function

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I struggle with the notation of the following problem or at least I am unsure what is asked for here:

Consider the Basis $B = \{ \begin{pmatrix} 
1  \\
2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 
-2  \\
1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\}          $ of $R^{2}$ and fine a linear mapping $D: R^{2} \to R^{2}$ by $Df_{1}=-f_{1}; Df_{2}=3*f_{2}$.

Give the matrix representation $A_{BB}$ and $A_{EE}$ of $D$, where $E$ is the standard basis of $R^{2}$.

So first of all I do not understand what $A_{BB}$ does really stand for? Why $BB$? I started out with computing the change of basis matrix $C$ for $R^{2}_{B} \to R^{2}_{E}$ and its inverse.

So $$C = \begin{pmatrix}  
        1/5 & 2/5  \\
        -2/5 & 1/5  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$ and $$C^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}  
        1 & -2  \\
        2 & 1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$
and the matrix $A_{B}$ that represents the mapping $D$ w.r.t. $B$

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}  
        11/5 & 8/3  \\
        8/5 & 4/3  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

But I do not know how to proceed since I am unsure what $A_{BB}$ stands for. Thanks!

Comment: $A_{BB}$ is the matrix which represents the linear map $D$ in which you've chosen to represent both elements of the domain and the codomain with respect to the basis $B$.  So if $A_{EE}$ is your standard matrix, then $A_{BB}$ is just $C^{-1}A_{EE}C$.

Comment: So $A_{EE}$ is the representation of D wrt basis $E$ as far as I understand?

Comment: Yes.$\ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: so it would be $A_{EE}  = \begin{pmatrix} 
-1 &  0\\
0 &  3\\
        \end{pmatrix}$ or?

Comment: Assuming $\{f_1, f_2\}$ is your standard basis, that is correct.  If not, you need some prescription of $f_1$ and $f_2$ to go any further.